# ignore zeros in org-mode table formula

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want a column formula that divides two cells, but ignore a row if the denumerator is zero.

Something like :

```
| 42 | 2 |          21 |
| 42 | 0 | round(42/0) |
#+TBLFM: $3=round($1/$2)
```

But with the third column empty instead of `round(42/0)`.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
| 42 | 2 | 21 |
| 42 | 0 |    |
#+TBLFM: $3=if($2>0,round($1/$2), string(""))
```

`string("")` is the way to denote an empty cell. This, and the `if()` syntax, are described [in the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc).

Comment: Hum, weird that I missed this page. Thanks.